# What type is the returned object from method?

Tags: java

I'm aware that when passing object as paramether, I'm actually passing a copy of this object, but what happens in this situation:

```
public Base myMethod ()
{
    Derived d = new Derived();
    return (Base) d;
}

Base b = myMethod();
```

Is the `b` object new object of type Base, or just pointer to downcasted Derived object allocated in heap in `myMethod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an object as a parameter, you pass a **copy of the reference** to the object.

Thus, in this case you return a copy of the reference that points to the object which is of type `Derived`.

Note that thanks to Garbage Collection, your object will remain safe as long as there is a handle to it but in C++ or something you would be left with undefined behaviour if you returned a pointer to something that was on the stack of the called function!

Comment: it is because java is a pass-by-value language. it always pass the value. I don't know whether it has a `ref` or `out` keywords to do otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're wrong: in Java, when passing an object as a parameter, you're actually passing a copy of the *reference*, (like passing a pointer in C or C++), so the object itself is never copied. Copy does occur with primitive types, such as int or boolean.

In your example, only one object is allocated: d, and, assuming Derived inherits from Base, that object is upcasted to type Base. In fact, the cast is redundant since upcasting is implicit in Java.

As a rule of thumb, just look for the `new` keyword: if it's there, you're creating a new object. Otherwise, you're just making a reference to an existing object.

Answer (score 1):

I is the latter one. It is just a pointer to an object of type `Derived`.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm aware that when passing object as paramether, I'm actually passing a copy of this object"

This is incorrect. You're passing a copy of a reference to the object.

To be precise, `b` isn't an object. It's a variable, and a variable in Java is never an object. It's either a primitive or an object reference (which you can think of as effectively being a pointer). So `b` is a reference of (static) type `Base` that refers-to/points-at an object of (dynamic/runtime) type `Derived`.

Answer (score 0):

Object in java is always kind of which that created by `new` , not depend on casting like C++.

Answer (score 0):

Okay what I know is:

Passing an object as a parameter, you are actually passing a reference of the object. So, you need to use .clone() to pass a copy of the object.

In your example your Base b is actually pointing a Derived type located in Heap.

```
public void name(Derived d)
{
  d.setName("hello");
}

//...

public static void main(String[] params)
{
   Derived demon = new Demon();
   name(demon);

   System.out.println(demon.getName()); // will print hello
}
```

Because you just passed a copy of the reference variable. It still refer to the actual object located in Heap.